# backup exchange 2010 mail boxes to exchange 2007

Tags: email, backup, exchange

i have one server running exchange 2010 with windows 2008 server.

i want to copy emails and user information from exchange 2010 to other server running exchange 2007, windows 2003.

is there any way i can do this ?

Thanks

Comment: This question is related to server administration, and will be better suited for Server Fault. I'm migrating your question there.

Answer (score 0):

I used the info available at: http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2010/management-administration/exporting-importing-mailboxes-exchange-server-2010.html

Powershell is pretty damn handy, scheduling exports and imports may make things much simpler for you if you only have one live install of exchange (that users actually connect to). Then again exporting your mailboxes to PST for a secondary backup is already a great step to be taking.

Comment: Exporting Mailboxes to PST for a secondary backup is not a great step to be taking.  Exchange 2007/ 2010 has the ability to have multiple copies of a single database for HA.  Additionally Backup Exec 2010 is "Exchange Aware" and can be used to restore individual items rather than an entire Database. Even for Legal Hold you have multiple options for dealing with those mailboxes rather than exporting the contents.

Answer (score 0):

Are the two servers in the same Exchange organization, or different ones?

If they are in the same org, then you can just move mailbox between them, either via EMC or PowerShell.

If they are in different orgs, you'll need to export data from one server to PST files and import them into the other one; have a look at the `Export-Mailbox` and `Import-Mailbox` cmdlets.